# Need Algorithm and implementation help - Compare 2 files

Tags: php, algorithm, implementation

My Project Purpose : There are 4 files.  Each of them has different number of lines.  Each line consists of a single or few words.  Now, for each of these files, I want to count which other file has the maximum common words.

- eg. (',' is a new line \n)
- **Input:**
- File 1 Lines : A,B,C,D
- File 2 Lines : C,D,E,F
- File 3 Lines : A,E,C,G
- File 4 Lines : C,E,F,A
- **Output :**
- File 1 : Maximum common words is 2 and they are in the files : File 2 (C,D), File 3 (A,C) and File 4 (C,A).
- File 2 : Maximum common words is 3 and they are in the files : File 4 (C,E,F).
- File 3 : Maximum common words is 3 and they are in the files : File 4 (C,E,A).
- File 4 : Maximum common words is 3 and they are in the files : File 2 (C,E,F).

My logic :

1. Start
2. Read each line from file and store it in memory as a 1-D array (eg.  array1[0] = "A", array1[1] = "B" and so on.
3. Since there are 4 files, I create 4 arrays = array1 to array4.  Each of them will have the contents of their corresponding files.
4. Now I will compare the first words in the first array with the first word in the second array.
5. Now I will compare the first words in the first array with the second word in the second array and so on till the end on second array.
6. I will continue this till the last word in the last array.
7. When ever I found something was matching I will note down in a variable by incrementing 1.

Wish to know if this is the right of approaching this problem.

Or is there a better way to think at this problem?

Edits : 
1.  Forgot to add, Will be using php.

Comment: I would save the found words in the files in an array like this: `if(isset($found_words_of_file_a[$word])) { $found_words_of_file_a[$word]++; } else { $found_words_of_file_a[$word] = 1; }`. As you can see the key is the word and the value is the total number of times the word is in the file. Easy access and easy comparison with the other arrays. I don't know what performence issues there are with using named indexes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easily done with [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Comment: Thanks for telling me a direct function

Comment: You're welcome, combine it with `count()` and you're half-way there with a really simple code that works great. :)

Answer (score 2):

I learned PHP from interesting situations like this. Keep on learning.

```
// put all files in same directory as this script
// put file names in this array
$files = array('1.txt','2.txt','3.txt','4.txt');
$words = array();
$data = '';

$delimiter = "\n";  // change this to \r if running windows OS
// itterate through the files and create a word list  
foreach($files as $file){
    $fh = fopen($file,'r');
    $data .= $delimiter.fread($fh,filesize($file));
    fclose($fh);
}
// assuming 1 match per line like your question example 
$lines = explode($delimiter,$data);

foreach($lines as $line){
    $line = trim($line);
    if(empty($line)) continue;
    @$words[$line] += 1;  // @ suppreses notices
}

var_dump($words);
/* *
 * according to your example:
 *
array(7) {
  ["A"]=>
  int(3)
  ["B"]=>
  int(1)
  ["C"]=>
  int(4)
  ["D"]=>
  int(2)
  ["E"]=>
  int(3)
  ["F"]=>
  int(2)
  ["G"]=>
  int(1)
} 
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the full logic :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should sort the arrays first. Then, to count the number of common lines between `array1` and `array2`, have two counters `i1` and `i2`.

Pseudo code:

```
while(i1 < array.length && i2 < array2.length)
  if array1[i1] == array2[i2]
    ++i1; ++i2
    ++result
  else if array1[i1] < array2[i2]
    ++i1
  else
    ++i2
```

Comment: Thanks for telling it should be sorted.  I do understand, in long run, this might save time